# How to handle an answer that answers the question, but doesn't involve programming?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, not-an-answer

In the Late Answers review queue, I came across an answer to [this self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370535/how-to-export-a-playlists-song-from-android-to-a-windows-pc/53856816#53856816) about how to write a batch file to perform a particular task.

The new answer, instead, suggested using an app to handle the task. It addresses the problem in the question, it isn't link-only, it passes all the superficial checks to count as "an answer," but it also has nothing to do with programming, so accepting it as a legitimate (if low-quality) answer would seem to imply that the question was off-topic.

Would it be valid to flag this answer, or should I just downvote it, or something else?

Comment: The irony of this duplicate choice is it has the accepted answer "the answer is fine, upvote it if you like"; but [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38752347/9209546) is now deleted by a mod.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with the dupe, that's not a high voted VLQ answer. NAA won't be applicable also.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's an answer that someone *thought* wasn't an answer, just as this person is asking if it's not.  Both of course are, for reasons specified, although answers of this type should, as mentioned in the duplicate, be checked to ensure they're not spam.  What do you feel there is to address in this case that's not covered by the duplicate?

Comment: This is hard. I'd say the only reason the _question_ is even near being on-topic is that the original answer is on topic. The question itself, if one does not take the self-answer into account, really belongs to SuperUser. The second answer is an appropriate answer to the question, and not having benefit of the other answer speaking for it, seems like off-topic.